# Label as Splash Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've been searching for hours now about my first task in my job. Today, I'm familiarising myself in using Macbook. It is really hard for me to adapt to changes, because I'm a Windows user. I used to be a freelance C# programmer.

Anyway, what I've learned in the first hour is the Storyboard. How to add a segue, for example, clicking a button from View1 and then the View2 will show. However, the program returns an error, I think I need to have a code first.

But let's go to the question: (How to make a splash screen with just a label not with an image)... I need to have a 1st screen which has a hello world label, and then after 2 seconds, the 2nd screen will show.

What I have done so far:

1. learned Story board.
2. checked the "Is initial view controller" of my first screen.

Comment: Thanks guys! I really appreciate all of your replies. I can't vote up yet your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new project it automatically create **LaunchScreen.xib**
1.) Now from Toolbar window select UILabel drag it to launchScreen.
2.) [image]

Answer (score 1):

For the Splash Screen in iOS Application You don't need to do code. You just need to following dimension Splash image and add it to asset.catalog.

**iPhone 4 & 4s size:**

Default.png (320px X 480px)

Default@2x.png (640px X 960px)

**iPhone 5 & 5s size:**

Default-568h.png (320px X 568px)

Default-568h@2x.png (640px X 1136px)

**iPhone 6**

Default-667h@2x.png (750px X 1334px)

**iPhone 6 Plush**

Default-736h@3x.png (1242px X 2208px)

---

This All iPhone Application splash screen size and its name conversation. now you can set Splash with two way:

**Fist:**

[image]

when you tap the right small arrow near of launchImage (->) you can see the following window:

[image]

Currently there is empty because from right side there is no any target selected so if your deployment target is 6.0 you need to set check mark like following screenshot so you can see the all image need box :

[image]

See when you add wrong dimension image in catalog you can get warning at top right corner and when you tap on this warning you can get actually dimension. see the following screenshot for:

[image]

So from the warning log you can know which dimension image need for which splash screen.

**Other way**

No need to use Asses Catalog and no need to use **LaunchScreen.xib** you can still use old way:

In plist you need to add following data:

- Add one row by tap (+) its called `UILaunchImages`

[image]

- and you need to fill this row like following

[image]

that's it no need to do any thing hope that answer helps to other as well.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Your Project(Right click) -> New File - >iOS -> User Interface -> View(Give any name to it).

This will create `nib` file with label(as your project name)

Now Open the Right Inspector of Xcode and check the `Use as Launch Screen` that's it ur work done.

Below i have attached screenshot which may help you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Launch Screen.xib(this is the splash screen which gets called automatically by xcode after an app is launched) --> clear everything u see inside the xib except the xib itself--> drag and drop a label in any position, write a text.